# Line-break without space with fop 2.2 but keeping white-space="pre" to manage user manually indented text

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

I'm trying to manage white space treatment within a text in Fop 2.2.

The text area includes long sentences and manually indented text.

`linefeed-treatment="preserve"` allows to have a correct linebreak at the end of the pdf page and white lines are kept. Which is great.

The problem is that I have to allow users to include manually indented text and manage it correctly. Here is an example :

> 1. Test 1
>
> ___1.1. Test 2
>
> ___1.2. Test 3
>
> ______1.2.1. Test 4
>
> ___1.3. Test 5
>
> 2. Test 6

In order to keep the indented text, I have to use `white-space="pre"` which is working great.

But then, the problem with `white-space="pre"` is that after a breakline, I have a space at the beginning of the next line.

I'm trying to find a solution that will allow to manage both situations but I can't find any.

Edit : More information about this.

Actually, the xml is generated from an application where the users can fill multi-lines text areas in. Each text area can include long sentences and indented text. All the content of one text area is one single tag. This is why it gets more difficult, because I have to manage both possibilities into one fo:block

Here is the XML tag that is generated by the application :

```
<TXT_TEST newline="1" title="0" style="txtArea" label="" unformattedLabel="" isModified="0" toPrint="1" indentation="0" xmlStyle="" nextField="">Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. 

Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. 

Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. Ceci est une zone de texte longue avec passage à la ligne forcé. 

Et voici une indentation forcée : 

1. Test
   1.1. Test
      1.1.1. Test
      1.1.2. Test
      1.1.3. Test
   1.2. Test
      1.2.1. Test
2. Test
3. Test</TXT_TEST>
```

But here is a link to the result I get right now, which is incorrect : [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9FN3.jpg)

Here is the fo-block i have in my xsl :

```
<fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space="pre" wrap-option="wrap" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="11pt">
<xsl:value-of select="TXT_TEST/text()"/>
</fo:block>
```

Comment: Replace all spaces at the start of the line with non-collapsing, non-breaking spaces in a template and for pre, keep-together.within-line always for each line

Comment: It would be better for you to post the actual XML and the XSL you have to see. I assume each line in it's own tag, but if not then then it becomes much more difficult

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thank you for your comment. I have updated my first message to include more information. Hope you can help.

Comment: What XSLT version are you using?  Your output will look even worse than your sample if  a user puts so much text in a list item that the list item wraps, so you may be better off parsing the text and putting `fo:block` around paragraphs, etc.  Parsing the list items will be easier if you are using XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 3.0 rather than XSLT 1.0. (Also, you don't need `/text()` in `TXT_TEST/text()` since `xsl:value-of` generates the string value anyway.)

Comment: I'm using XSLT 1.0.
I did what you talked about, parsing the text arear into lines and manage lines one by one, depending on the situation. It is working great but obviously, the process is a little bit more complicated. I made a template of it so it wil be easier to call it every time I'm managing a textarea (and I'm managing several of them in every possible documents users can create).
I'll answer my question with the code I'm using, so anyone who needs it can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @TonyGraham, I did a parse of the textarea, so I was able to process line by line. Here is the code I used :

```
<xsl:template name="split-textarea">
    <xsl:param name="texta" />

    <xsl:choose >
        <xsl:when test="contains($texta,'&#xa;')">  
            <xsl:variable name="textbefore" select="substring-before($texta,'&#xa;')" />
            <xsl:variable name="textafter" select="substring-after($texta,'&#xa;')"/>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with($textbefore, ' ')">
                    <fo:block wrap-option="wrap" white-space="pre" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="11pt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$textbefore" />
                    </fo:block>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <fo:block wrap-option="wrap" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="11pt">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$textbefore != ''">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$textbefore" />
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <fo:block>&#xA0;</fo:block>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </fo:block>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:call-template name="split-textarea">
                <xsl:with-param name="texta" select="$textafter" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:block font-family="Helvetica" font-size="11pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="$texta" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>&#xA0;</fo:block>
        </xsl:otherwise>        
    </xsl:choose>       
</xsl:template>
```